# Is a new ID assigned to a parsed prepared statement if the statement is the same?

Tags: cassandra, prepared-statement

Cassandra : When Cassandra assign an id to a parsed statement, will it assign a new id if same statement is issued to different Cassandra node or if the same statement  originates from different Microservice?

Tried to search the Cassandra official documentation but did not get anything there.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which language you're using, but fortunately the drivers are similarly engineered in this regard.

So there are two prepared statement caches.  One in the cluster itself, which is kept in-sync by the driver.  When a prepared statement is run, the driver tries it on one node.  If that node succeeds, then it is prepared on the remaining nodes in the cluster.

> When a statement is initially prepared, it is first sent to a single node in the cluster (this avoids hitting all nodes in case the query string is wrong). Once that node replies successfully, the driver re-prepares on all remaining nodes.

This way, any future requests using that prepared statement ID will match, regardless of which node handles the initial preparation.

> or if the same statement originates from different Microservice?

So the driver also has a prepared statement cache.  Obviously, a different microservice is going to have its own instance of the driver, and those driver caches won't match-up.  However...

> The prepared statement identifier is deterministic (it’s a hash of the query string), so it is the same for all nodes.

Likewise, the same query from different applications *should* match-up.  So different microservices could indeed share prepared statements in the Cassandra-side cache.

Driver 4.17.0 Java Doc reference: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.17/manual/core/statements/prepared/

Comment: Thanks for your response. It Really helped me to understand how prepared statement works at Cassandra level and at driver level.